# What is this error when downloading apache-superset on virtual environment using cmd?

Tags: python, virtualenv, apache-superset

I got question about downloading apache-superset. I used virtual environment to install the apache-spark. my python version is 3.12.0

```
>pip install apache-superset
Collecting apache-superset
  Using cached apache-superset-3.0.2.tar.gz (48.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting backoff>=1.8.0 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached backoff-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting celery<6.0.0,>=5.2.2 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached celery-5.3.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (21 kB)
Collecting click>=8.0.3 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting click-option-group (from apache-superset)
  Using cached click_option_group-0.5.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.3 kB)
Collecting colorama (from apache-superset)
  Using cached colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting croniter>=0.3.28 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached croniter-2.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (24 kB)
Collecting cron-descriptor (from apache-superset)
  Using cached cron_descriptor-1.4.0.tar.gz (29 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting cryptography<40,>=39.0.1 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached cryptography-39.0.2-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (2.5 MB)
Collecting deprecation<2.2.0,>=2.1.0 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached deprecation-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting flask<3.0.0,>=2.2.5 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached flask-2.3.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
Collecting flask-appbuilder<5.0.0,>=4.3.10 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached Flask_AppBuilder-4.3.10-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.9 kB)
Collecting flask-caching<3,>=2.1.0 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached Flask_Caching-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Collecting flask-compress<2.0,>=1.13 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached Flask_Compress-1.14-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.8 kB)
Collecting flask-talisman<2.0,>=1.0.0 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached flask_talisman-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (18 kB)
Collecting flask-login<1.0,>=0.6.0 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached Flask_Login-0.6.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Collecting flask-migrate<4.0,>=3.1.0 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached Flask_Migrate-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting flask-wtf<2.0,>=1.1.0 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached flask_wtf-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.4 kB)
Collecting func_timeout (from apache-superset)
  Using cached func_timeout-4.3.5.tar.gz (44 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting geopy (from apache-superset)
  Using cached geopy-2.4.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.8 kB)
Collecting hashids<2,>=1.3.1 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached hashids-1.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
Collecting holidays<0.24,>=0.23 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached holidays-0.23-py3-none-any.whl (485 kB)
Collecting humanize (from apache-superset)
  Using cached humanize-4.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.9 kB)
Collecting importlib_metadata (from apache-superset)
  Using cached importlib_metadata-7.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.9 kB)
Collecting isodate (from apache-superset)
  Using cached isodate-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
Collecting Mako>=1.2.2 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached Mako-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.9 kB)
Collecting markdown>=3.0 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached Markdown-3.5.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.1 kB)
Collecting msgpack<1.1,>=1.0.0 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached msgpack-1.0.7-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (9.4 kB)
Collecting nh3<0.3,>=0.2.11 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached nh3-0.2.15-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
Collecting numpy==1.23.5 (from apache-superset)
  Using cached numpy-1.23.5.tar.gz (10.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [33 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Kayleen\testing_apache\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Kayleen\testing_apache\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Kayleen\testing_apache\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          backend = _build_backend()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Kayleen\testing_apache\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
          obj = import_module(mod_path)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Kayleen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1304, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 929, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\Kayleen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6ihq1sxh\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
          import setuptools.version
        File "C:\Users\Kayleen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6ihq1sxh\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
          import pkg_resources
        File "C:\Users\Kayleen\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6ihq1sxh\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2172, in <module>
          register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have downloaded python newest version which is 3.12.0 but it still wont work, i have downloaded setuptools too and upgrade it to the lastest version. Does anyone know how to fix this so i can run apache-superset without using ubuntu? There are some missing modules there but i dont know how to fix it and tried to download it and it still not working

Comment: You're running `pip` installed in a Python installation at `C:\Users\Kayleen\testing_apache`, while your Python 3.12 is installed in `C:\Users\Kayleen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312`. Clearly the former installation of Python is of an earlier incompatible version.

Comment: Sorry, what do i have to do to fix that? should i uninstall all?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to install anything, but you should run `pip` installed in `C:\Users\Kayleen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312` instead. You can likely find it as `C:\Users\Kayleen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Scripts\pip.exe`.

Comment: Activate your virtual environment before using `pip`. Use `source <venv>\Scripts\activate` command in the terminal then run the installation.

Comment: @blhsing hi, im sorry but can you tell me step by step how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that works currently is to downgrade from python3.12 to something less.
I went through `apache-superset`'s setup.cfg, and it lists only 3 version of python that it supports, which are versions 3.9, 3.10, 3.11

```
Metadata-Version: 2.1
Name: apache-superset
Version: 3.1.1
Summary: A modern, enterprise-ready business intelligence web application
Home-page: https://superset.apache.org/
Author: Apache Software Foundation
Author-email: dev@superset.apache.org
License: Apache License, Version 2.0
Download-URL: https://www.apache.org/dist/superset/3.1.1
Platform: UNKNOWN
Classifier: Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9
Classifier: Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10
Classifier: Programming Language :: Python :: 3.11
Requires-Python: ~=3.9
```

setup.py lists `numpy==1.23.5` as one of the required installs (dependencies), and, according to your screenshot, the error is raised when the setup tries to install `numpy==1.23.5`, whose pkg-info lists

```
Classifier: Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8  
Classifier: Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9  
Classifier: Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10  
Classifier: Programming Language :: Python :: 3.11
Classifier: Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only
```

The last line does not guarantee compatibility with `Python==3.12` though, and the fact that there is no guarantee might be the reason of the error. I tried installing `numpy==1.23.5` on `Python==3.12` as a standalone (that is, independently of apache-superset), and still got the same error.
I also combed through `numpy==1.23.5`'s `setup.py`, and discovered that it imports the `ImpImporter`, which has been deprecated sinc `Python3.3` and is removed from `Python3.12`.
The problem, then, is `numpy==1.23.5`'s compatibility with `Python==3.12`.
The only way to get `apache-superset` to work is to downgrade to `python >=3.9,<3.12`.